# Hostname in certificate didn't match in OAuth request

Tags: java, ssl, https, oauth, keytool

I have created certificate through openssl

```
Openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout tls.key -out tls.crt -subj "/CN=nginxsvc/O=nginxsvc"
```

and import `tls.crt` through keytool in java as well

```
keytool -import -file C:\Code_Base\Certificates\NGINX_150\tls.crt -storepass changeit -keystore "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\security\cacerts"
```

But i am getting

> 16:30:21,046 ERROR [org.keycloak.adapters.OAuthRequestAuthenticator]
>   (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) failed to turn code into token:
>   javax.net.ssl.SSLException: hostname in certificate didn't match:
>   <135.209.100.150> !=    at
>   org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:238)
>   [httpclient-4.3.6.redhat-1.jar:4.3.6.redhat-1]    at
>   org.apache.http.conn.ssl.BrowserCompatHostnameVerifier.verify(BrowserCompatHostnameVerifier.java:54)
>   [httpclient-4.3.6.redhat-1.jar:4.3.6.redhat-1]    at
>   org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:159)
>   [httpclient-4.3.6.redhat-1.jar:4.3.6.redhat-1]    at
>   org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:140)
>   [httpclient-4.3.6.redhat-1.jar:4.3.6.redhat-1]    at
>   org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.verifyHostname(SSLSocketFactory.java:561)
>   [httpclient-4.3.6.redhat-1.jar:4.3.6.redhat-1]    at
>   org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:536)
>   [httpclient-4.3.6.redhat-1.jar:4.3.6.redhat-1]    at
>   org.keycloak.adapters.SniSSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SniSSLSocketFactory.java:109)
>   [keycloak-adapter-core-2.4.0.Final.jar:2.4.0.Final]   at
>   org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:403)
>   [httpclient-4.3.6.redhat-1.jar:4.3.6.redhat-1]    at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:177)
>   [httpclient-4.3.6.redhat-1.jar:4.3.6.redhat-1]    at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:144)
>   [httpclient-4.3.6.redhat-1.jar:4.3.6.redhat-1]    at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:131)
>   [httpclient-4.3.6.redhat-1.jar:4.3.6.redhat-1]    at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:611)
>   [httpclient-4.3.6.redhat-1.jar:4.3.6.redhat-1]    at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:446)
>   [httpclient-4.3.6.redhat-1.jar:4.3.6.redhat-1]    at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:863)
>   [httpclient-4.3.6.redhat-1.jar:4.3.6.redhat-1]    at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
>   [httpclient-4.3.6.redhat-1.jar:4.3.6.redhat-1]    at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:106)
>   [httpclient-4.3.6.redhat-1.jar:4.3.6.redhat-1]    at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
>   [httpclient-4.3.6.redhat-1.jar:4.3.6.redhat-1]    at
>   org.keycloak.adapters.ServerRequest.invokeAccessCodeToToken(ServerRequest.java:107)
>   [keycloak-adapter-core-2.4.0.Final.jar:2.4.0.Final]   at
>   org.keycloak.adapters.OAuthRequestAuthenticator.resolveCode(OAuthRequestAuthenticator.java:327)
>   [keycloak-adapter-core-2.4.0.Final.jar:2.4.0.Final]   at
>   org.keycloak.adapters.OAuthRequestAuthenticator.authenticate(OAuthRequestAuthenticator.java:273)
>   [keycloak-adapter-core-2.4.0.Final.jar:2.4.0.Final]   at
>   org.keycloak.adapters.RequestAuthenticator.authenticate(RequestAuthenticator.java:130)
>   [keycloak-adapter-core-2.4.0.Final.jar:2.4.0.Final]   at
>   org.keycloak.adapters.tomcat.AbstractKeycloakAuthenticatorValve.authenticateInternal(AbstractKeycloakAuthenticatorValve.java:208)
>   [keycloak-tomcat-core-adapter-2.4.0.Final.jar:2.4.0.Final]    at
>   org.keycloak.adapters.jbossweb.KeycloakAuthenticatorValve.authenticate(KeycloakAuthenticatorValve.java:39)
>   [keycloak-as7-adapter-2.4.0.Final.jar:2.4.0.Final]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
>   [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   org.keycloak.adapters.tomcat.AbstractKeycloakAuthenticatorValve.invoke(AbstractKeycloakAuthenticatorValve.java:187)
>   [keycloak-tomcat-core-adapter-2.4.0.Final.jar:2.4.0.Final]    at
>   org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169)
>   [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:150)
>   [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97)
>   [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102)
>   [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344)
>   [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:854)
>   [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653)
>   [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:926)
>   [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [rt.jar:1.8.0_152]

Comment: Please show the URL you are using to connect to the service. ***`CN=nginxsvc`*** is probably wrong. Hostnames always go in the *SAN*. If its present in the *CN*, then it must be present in the *SAN* too (you have to list it twice in this case). For more rules and reasons, see [How do you sign Certificate Signing Request with your Certification Authority](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21340898/608639) and [How to create a self-signed certificate with openssl?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10175812/608639)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common name mismatch error occurs when the [common name](https://www.ssl.com/faqs/common-name/) (or [SAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject_Alternative_Name)s) of your SSL/TLS certificate does not match the host + domain name that another service connects to when trying to reach your service.

Your CommonName (CN=nginxsvc) should match the host and domain name / IP of the service. So if your service is at `nginxservice.yourdomain.com`, the certificate commonname should also be `nginxservice.yourdomain.com`. If you are using an IP just for development purposes, you can also use that until you have a DNS entry for your service.

Comment: Thanks for your reply so its better use `Openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout tls.key -out tls.crt -subj "/CN=<IP Address of machine>/O=<IP Address of machine>"` as i didn't give any DNS name in my virtual server